# Set marks on "checkedlistbox" using data taken from "datagridview"

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkedlistbox

**I** want to edit a record in the "datagridview", and after clicking on a specific record, I need to extract the data from the columns into the filling elements. I don't understand how it can be done with "checkedlistbox".
**Is** it realistic to implement the corresponding creation of marks on "checkedlistbox"?
**Would **it be correct to use a for loop to compare elements?

I am trying to do this to edit records with "datagridview".

*Clicking on a column:*

```
private void DGV3_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        txtName.Text = DGV3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
        txtType.Text = DGV3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["type"].Value.ToString();
        cmbCoash.SelectedItem = DGV3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["сoach"].Value.ToString();

// try to mark the elements:
                dayp = DGV3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["trainingdays"].Value.ToString();
                string[] mystring = dayp.Split(',');

                foreach (var item in mystring)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var listItem in chDay.Items)
                    {
                        if ((string)listItem == item)
                        {
                            chDay.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
        try
        {
            key = Convert.ToInt32(DGV3.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

*chDay - checkedlistbox*

[image: Line view:]

Comment: You forgot to `i++` in the inner `foreach` after the `if` block.